# Using Neo4j with Jersey 2.x API

Tags: java, jersey, neo4j, jersey-2.0

I am trying to use a Neo4j server with the jersey 2 API, but am having difficulty rewriting the the examples in the neo4j from jersey 1.x to 2.x. E.g. here is the first example is:

```
WebResource resource = Client.create().resource( SERVER_ROOT_URI );
ClientResponse response = resource.get( ClientResponse.class );
System.out.println( String.format( "GET on [%s], status code [%d]",SERVER_ROOT_URI, response.getStatus() ) );
response.close();
```

Which can be rewritten as:

```
String baseURI = new String("http://localhost:7474/");
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(baseURI);
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
```

But when I try to rewrite the second example I get stuck:

```
final String nodeEntryPointUri = SERVER_ROOT_URI + "node"; //http://localhost:7474/db/data/node
WebResource resource = Client.create().resource( nodeEntryPointUri );
// POST {} to the node entry point URI
ClientResponse response = resource.accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ).type( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ).entity( "{}" ).post( ClientResponse.class );
```

THis should look something like:

```
String baseURI = new String("http://localhost:7474/");
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(baseURI).path(newnode);
Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(Entity.entity("{}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
System.out.println(postResponse.getStatus());
```

but this returns http 404. How should the request be structured instead>?

Have answered this myself: COde fragment should be:

```
String baseURI = new String("http://localhost:7474/"); 
Client client2 = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target2 = client2.target(baseURI + "db/data/node");
System.out.println(target2.getUri());
Response postResponse = target2.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(Entity.entity(JSON , MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
    System.out.println(postResponse.getStatus() + "     " + postResponse.getLocation());
    postResponse.close();
```

Comment: In the 1.x examples you include the `/db/data/` path in the root uri, but in the 2.x code you don't (at least not in the first example). Are you possibly posting to `localhost:7474/node` by accident?

Comment: I have tried both and neither work. I am not sure which one is right, but I think the problem is in the Response/post line.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer. You could also improve your answer by explaining what the problem was and what you changed to fix it.